# Why this failed

Tags: prolog

I'm a beginner in Prolog after 40 years of imperative programming.

```
#!/usr/bin/swipl
:- use_module(library(clpfd)).

all_digits( [] ).
all_digits( [H|T] ) :-
   memberchk( H, [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9] ),
   all_digits( T ).

:-
   is_list( A ),
   length( A, 3 ),
   all_digits( A ),
   halt( 0 ).
```

This program is in progress, I have another rules to add, but it already failed.

Why?

I expect 720 solutions: `n!(n−p)!` because each digit must be used only once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without using clpfd:

```
uniq_digits_3(L) :-
    % Assemble list of [0, 1, ..., 9]
    numlist(0, 9, Digits),
    % Restrict length, so selects/2 knows when to stop
    length(L, 3),
    selects(L, Digits).

selects([], _Ys).
selects([X|Xs], Ys) :-
    % Take 1 element from Ys
    select(X, Ys, Ys0),
    % Loop with the remaining Ys0
    selects(Xs, Ys0).
```

Result in swi-prolog:

```
?- bagof(L, uniq_digits_3(L), Ls), length(Ls, LsLen).
Ls = [[0, 1, 2], [0, 1, 3], ...
LsLen = 720.
```

Answer (score 4):

`is_list( A )` fails since `A` is not a list when the predicate is called. You can remove it. Moreover, you do not need, in this snippet, the clpfd library. Finally, note that `memberchk/2`, after a success, cuts all the remaining solutions. If you want to generate all the solutions, you should use `member/2`.

Moreover, you define a list of three elements, and each one can be a number between 0 and 9. So you will get 10*3 = 1000 solutions, instead of the 720 you expect.

Answer (score 4):

The query fails because of `is_list/1` since `A` is a variable.

Using `clpfd`, you can replace `all_digits(A)` with `A ins 0..9`. The list is of length 3 and each element can have 10 possible values if the value of `A` is enumerated then there should be 1000 solutions.

The query rewritten:

```
:- use_module(library(clpfd)).

?- length(Vs, 3), Vs ins 0..9, all_distinct(Vs), label(Vs).
```

The predicate `all_distinct/1` is used to constraint each variable of `Vs` to be distinct and the predicate `label/1` is used to find a solution.